# Can I write "His ideas are strategically and linguistically structured"?

Tags: adverbs

Can I write this:

> His ideas are strategically and linguistically structured.

Can I use two adverbs separated by "and"?

Comment: Easy. Just *do it [adverb1] and [adverb2]*. For example: *Please ask your question **clearly and politely***.

Comment: This is an editing question. And those are not really allowed.

Comment: What makes you think you cannot? Please make sure to show research and ideas in your post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your example would mean, but you can definitely use two adverbs coordinated by "and", for example:

> This car can get you quickly and economically to your destination.
>
> The cook quickly and deftly chopped the vegetables.